# ¿Cómo limpiar el historial de un repositorio tras un fork?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fork, git-tag

Tengo un proyecto en un repositorio **git** con el código de una aplicación (*App1* en adelante).

Me han pedido crear una segunda aplicación muy similar. De hecho, es casi una segunda instancia de App1, con lo que he hecho lo obvio: crear un *fork* del repositorio y empezar a modificar lo que va a ser distinto. Hasta aquí no hay problemas.

Lo que no sé cómo resolver es el tema de las etiquetas: cada vez que despliego una nueva versión, usando [*semver*](https://semver.org/lang/es/), creo una etiqueta: v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v2.0.0 ... etc. El problema es que en el nuevo proyecto quisiera *nombrar* al primer despliegue en producción App2 v1.0.0, pero la etiqueta v1.0.0 (y un par de docenas más) ya está usada.

¿Puedo borrar de un modo sencillo todas las etiquetas en mi fork? ¿Puede tener alguna consecuencia inesperada?

Comment: Podrías probar a borrar el tag con git push origin :tagname y crear uno nuevo con git tag <tagname>? Yo uso SourceTree y me resulta mas sencillo que usar los comandos pero esto ya es opinión personal, supongo que para el incremento de versión usas algún script?

Comment: ¿necesitas realmente el historial del repositorio previo? ¿No podría ser más útil simplemente borrar la carpeta `.git` tras el `fork`  y luego hacer un `git init .` para empezar un nuevo historial de cero? En el primer commit de esta nueva historia meterías toda la carpeta de trabajo.

Comment: @abulafia Es una opción que también estoy pensando, no sé si tener el historial común en ambos repositorios me sirve de algo

Comment: Si vas a hacer un repositorio nuevo no te recomendaría que lo creases desde cero e hicieses un único commit con todo lo que llevas hasta ahora. En primer lugar pierdes toda la historia de lo que ha pasado, te va a costar comparar ramas actuales con ramas antiguas, etc. Además, al commitear a tu nombre te estás responsabilizando de todo lo que haya hecho hasta ahora. Cuando algo falle, va a salir siempre tu nombre aunque haya sido gañanada de algún compañero tuyo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas Linux, puedes usar esta línea:

```
$ git tag -l '*' | while read tag; git tag -d $tag; git push origin :$tag; done
```

Funciona así:

- **`git tag -l '*'`**: Lista todas las etiquetas
- **`git tag -d $tag`**: Borra la etiqueta localmente
- **`git push origin :$tag`**: Borra la etiqueta en el remoto (Subiendo una referencia vacía)

En cuanto a la segunda pregunta no se me ocurren consecuencias inesperadas. Tal vez hayan referencias en los commits o en el código refiriendose a las etiquetas.

Otra opción es renombrar los tags actuales por "App1-TAG" y conservar coherencia en la historia. Creo que podría hacerse así:

```
$ git tag -l '*' | while read tag; git tag App1-$tag $tag; git tag -d $tag; git push origin :$tag; done; git push --tags
```

---

En mi opinión, es buena idea conservar el histórico de App1 en el repo nuevo (como lo recomienda @ordago), y a partir del *fork* continuar con el desarrollo independiente, borrando las ramas fuera de la *master* y las etiquetas.